# Negating previously matched word group

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract content from a string that looks like this:

```
A.content content 
  content 
B.content  C. content content
content D.content
```

And here is my regex pattern in Python:

```
reg = re.compile(r''' 
     (?xi)
     (\w\.\t*\s*)+ (?# e.g. A. or b.)
     (.+)          (?# the alphanumeric content with common symbols)
     ^(?:\1)       (?# e.g. 'not A.' or 'not b.')
     ''')

m = reg.findall(s)
```

Let me give you an example. Say I have the following string:

```
s = '''
 a.   $1000 abcde!?
 b.  (December 31, 1993.)
 c.  8/1/2013
 d.   $690 * 10% = 69 Blah blah
'''
```

The following regex **works** and returns to me the contents of the regex group:

```
reg = re.compile(r'''
            (?xi)
            \w\.\t*
            ([^\n]+) (?# anything not newline char)
''')

for c in reg.findall(s): print "line:", c
>>>line:    $1000 abcde!?
>>>line:  (December 31, 1993.)
>>>line:    8/1/2013
>>>line:   $690 * 10% = 69 Blah blah
```

**But** if the contents bleed over into the another line, the regex **does not work**.

```
s = '''
   a.   $1000 abcde!? B.     December 
   31, 1993 c.  8/1/2013 D.   $690 * 10% = 
   69 Blah blah
'''
reg = re.compile(r''' 
     (?xi)
     (\w\.\t*\s*)+ (?# e.g. A. or b.)
     (.+)          (?# the alphanumeric content with common symbols)
     ^(?:\1)       (?# e.g. 'not A.' or 'not b.')
     ''')
for c in reg.findall(s): print "line:", c # no matches :(
>>> blank :(
```

I would like to get the same matches no matter if there was a newline separating the content or not.

That's why I tried using a negating match word group. So any ideas on how I can solve this problem either with regex or some other workaround?

Thanks.

Paul

Comment: Do you have some sample matches/non-matches? It's a little difficult to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my question to give examples and output.

Comment: This is still very mysterious. Could you post what matches you would have liked to get, and how they differ from the ones you're actually getting?

Comment: I get no matches. I would like to match the content in between A. or B. or C. etc. no matter if there was a newline separating them. Example:
 "A. contenta B. contentb C. contentc"
should get me a list:
['contenta','contentb', 'contentc']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think*  I understand what you want. You want to split

```
a.   $1000 abcde!? B.     December 
31, 1993 c.  8/1/2013 D.   $690 * 10% = 
69 Blah blah
```

into

- `a.   $1000 abcde!?`
- `B.     December \n31, 1993`
- `c.  8/1/2013`
- `D.   $690 * 10% = \n69 Blah blah`

Right? Then negative lookahead assertions are what you want:

```
reg = re.compile(r''' 
     (?xs)               # no need for i, but for s (dot matches newlines)
     (\b\w\.\s*)         # e.g. A. or b. (word boundary to restrict to 1 letter)
     ((?:(?!\b\w\.).)+)  # everything until the next A. or b.
     ''')
```

Use it with `findall()`:

```
>>> reg.findall(s)
[('a.   ', '$1000 abcde!? '), ('B.     ', 'December \n   31, 1993 '), 
 ('c.  ', '8/1/2013 '), ('D.   ', '$690 * 10% = \n   69 Blah blah\n')]
```

If you don't want the `a.` parts, use

```
reg = re.compile(r''' 
     (?xs)               # no need for i, but for s (dot matches newlines)
     (?:\b\w\.\s*)       # e.g. A. or b. (word boundary to restrict to 1 letter)
     ((?:(?!\b\w\.).)+)  # everything until the next A. or b.
     ''')
```

Comment: That's awesome. Regexs are really powerful if you know how to use them. Many thanks! :)